# How to implement substitutions?

Tags: perl, sendgrid

I am using the Email::SendGrid::V3 Perl library and my goal is to send one e-mail to many recipients by greeting them using their first name. I however cannot figure out how to perform the personalization using their online documentation:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::SendGrid::V3#$self-%3Eset_section($key,-$value);

I can send a single email to two different persons but I lack information on how to approach the body substitutions.

```
use Email::SendGrid::V3;

my $sg = Email::SendGrid::V3->new(api_key => 'ABCDE');

my $result = $sg->from('noreply@mydomain.com')
->subject('This is a subject line')
->add_envelope( to => [ {email => 'john@mydomain.com', name => 'John Smith' }] )
->set_section('-NAME-', 'John')
->add_content('text/html', 'Hello -NAME-, how are you?')
->send;

print $result->{success} ? "It worked" : "It failed: " . $result->{reason};
```

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the chance to get quick feedback from the developer, and the solution is the following:

```
my $result = $sg->from('noreply@mydomain.com')
->subject('This is a subject line')
->add_content('text/html', 'Hello -NAME-, how are you?')
->add_envelope( to => [ {email => 'fred@mydomain.com', name => 'Fred Smith' }], substitutions => { '-NAME-' => 'Fred' } )
->add_envelope( to => [ {email => 'john@mydomain.com', name => 'John Smith' }], substitutions => { '-NAME-' => 'John' } )
->send;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just templating; you have a template, and you want to fill in values. [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template) is a straightforward implementation of this, though since your result is HTML, you want an HTML-aware template engine like [Text::Xslate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Xslate) or [Mojo::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Template) so you don't have to remember to HTML-escape each value. There is also [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) that is the overall most-used and most configurable templating system. Below is an example using Mojo::Template.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::Template;

my $mt = Mojo::Template->new(vars => 1, auto_escape => 1);
my $template = 'Hello <%= $name %>, how are you?';
my $rendered = $mt->render($template, {name => 'John'});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I get what you are saying. Should I then assume I will need to use the send methods several times, one for each recipient? I actually tried to specify two add_content in the same block but it didn't like it.

Comment: @Questionz Yes; since each recipient needs different contents, they need to be sent as separate emails.

Comment: @Questionz I actually missed that SendGrid does templating itself; you could certainly use it for this, though you'll need to keep in mind the HTML escaping I mentioned, and it does still look like each needs to be sent separately.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I really thought the API would be able to handle substitutions from reading their documention. As they say its possible to add a substitution hash within the envelope and thought that was it.

Comment: @Questionz If it is possible, I suspect it would by adding multiple envelopes each with their own 'substitutions' hash directly in the add_envelope call. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation for what that hash actually is.

Comment: Thanks a mil for your help !